# Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, make, patch

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server and re-complied whole kernel with my patches. Now at the stage of installing it, but when I runs `sudo make install` I'm seeing following error,

```
root@localhost:/home/linux-5.4# sudo make install
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 5.4.0 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
        System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 5.4.0 /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 5.4.0 /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0 with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/boot/Makefile:155: install] Error 1
make: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:293: install] Error 2
```

Here is how much space left on my server with `df -i` command,

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            114642    367  114275    1% /dev
tmpfs           125596    500  125096    1% /run
/dev/sda       1568000 271637 1296363   18% /
tmpfs           125596      4  125592    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           125596      3  125593    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           125596     18  125578    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

`df-h` output,

```
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev            448M     0  448M   0% /dev
    tmpfs            99M   12M   87M  12% /run
    /dev/sda         25G   22G  2.2G  92% /
    tmpfs           491M     0  491M   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    tmpfs           491M     0  491M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

It's worth noting that df-h was long list of file names before and now it print correctly.

Comment: What's ```df -h``` output?

Comment: @Chuck See edit.

Comment: You are very close to being full on your root partition. Have you thought about deleting a couple gigs of data and trying ```sudo make install``` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with installing Kernel first then ran make clean, then proceed with installing Modules. This approach saves the needed space.